# Add user email scope to Google OAuth

Tags: api, google-oauth

I completed the process to allow the users to login to Google OAuth but the Oauth Consent Screen do not ask the email/userinfo permission/scope to the user and so the access token I get do not have access to the user information.

At *console.cloud.google.com > My project > Credentials > Oauth Consent Screen* the following scopes are visible but seem added by default and I can not edit them: email (googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email), profile (googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile), openid (openid)

[image]

But when I test it I get this dialog window:

[image]

Instead I should get this:

[image]

So with the text "*To continue, Google will share your name, email address, language preference, and profile picture with Support Board*."

My app is not verified by Google and maybe this is the issue, but after checking everywhere I do not see any docs about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the URL must include; **`scope=email`**

For instance:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=[URL]&client_id=[CLIENT-ID]&prompt=consent
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```